# How can I make these two things happen at same time when mouse roll over in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, rollover

I have a movie clip called content. I want that when the mouse roll over the button, the content shows up and start playing the animation. Right now, When I mouse over, it play the movie clip, when I roll-out, it disappear which works fine. But the problem is the next time when I roll over again, nothing shows up. Any idea? Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

code of the btn

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, test);
function test(event:MouseEvent):void{
    content.visible=true;
    content.play();
}


btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, test2);
    function test2(event:MouseEvent):void{
    content.visible=false;
}
```

code for the movie clip:

```
Stop(); // 1st frame
Stop(); // last frame
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replay your movie by using [gotoAndPlay()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndPlay%28%29)

```
function test(event:MouseEvent):void{
    content.visible=true;
    content.gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```